# Formatting a 3d bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, axis, matplotlib-3d

I am working with this code example

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
[0,1,0,2,0],
[0,3,0,2,0],
[6,1,1,7,0],
[0,5,0,2,9],
[0,1,0,4,0],
[9,1,3,4,2],
[0,0,2,1,3],
])

column_names = ['a','b','c','d','e']
row_names = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

lx= len(data[0])            # Work out matrix dimensions
ly= len(data[:,0])
xpos = np.arange(0,lx,1)    # Set up a mesh of positions
ypos = np.arange(0,ly,1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()   # Convert positions to 1D array
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(lx*ly)

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = data.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b')

#sh()
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(column_names)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_names)
ax.set_xlabel('Letter')
ax.set_ylabel('Day')
ax.set_zlabel('Occurrence')

plt.show()
```

and I have successfully adapted it to my needs now I need to change the colours for each column to make my data more readable as shown in this other example http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html but as the graphs are constructed in totally different ways I cannot figure out how to apply one to the other

Answer (score 12, accepted):

basically, you just pass an array of colors to `color=`. Each element of the array is one of your bars. So depending on how you construct your array, you can group your bars by `columns` or by `rows`.

for example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

data = np.array([
[0,1,0,2,0],
[0,3,0,2,0],
[6,1,1,7,0],
[0,5,0,2,9],
[0,1,0,4,0],
[9,1,3,4,2],
[0,0,2,1,3],
])

column_names = ['a','b','c','d','e']
row_names = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

lx= len(data[0])            # Work out matrix dimensions
ly= len(data[:,0])
xpos = np.arange(0,lx,1)    # Set up a mesh of positions
ypos = np.arange(0,ly,1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()   # Convert positions to 1D array
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(lx*ly)

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = data.flatten()

cs = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c'] * ly

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=cs)

#sh()
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(column_names)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_names)
ax.set_xlabel('Letter')
ax.set_ylabel('Day')
ax.set_zlabel('Occurrence')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I really am new to python but can you also show me how to colour by day of the week I tried just reversing the matrix and I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @PeterDoro to group by day of the week you'd use a color array like this     `cs = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r',
      'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g',
      'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',
      'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y',
      'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c',
      'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k',
      'grey', 'grey', 'grey', 'grey', 'grey']`

of course, that only works if your number of bars is always the same. Otherwise you'll have to programatically construct an array with the right shape and the right repetition of colors to match your data